# Why is the trajectory of object in xOy plane - given by y=y0+vyvxx-x0

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

[image]

The answer here is c) $y=y0+vyvxx-x0$

**Why is this the case?**

If

- $vy=$ velocity in the y direction (not stated in the question, but I am assuming it is)
- $vx$=velocity in the x direction
- $x$ displacement in the $x$ direction

Would would I multiply these out? This would give me the units $m/s$ * $m/s$ * $m$ = $m^3/s^2$ ... which is not a distance unit (which I expect as trajectory is given by $y=$....)

Also, why would the $y$ position have anything to do with the velocity in the x direction, $vx$, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken formatting in the texts you show, must cause some crucial notation to be disappearing. As your unit analysis correctly shows, the shown answer must be wrong.

I believe the division line of a fraction has disappeared. And also some brackets of some reason. Correct combination would rather be something like:

Isolating $t$ in the $x$-equation (case I):

$$t=\frac{x-x_0}{v_x}$$

Inserting in the $y$-equation:

$$y=y_0+v_y \left(\frac{x-x_0}{v_x}\right)\\
y=y_0+\frac{v_y}{v_x}(x-x_0)$$

This is fairly close to the answer (c).

---

It's not because the y-direction *depends* on the x-direction and x-velocity. It just *can* be expressed with it, because they have something in common (the time $t$). Remember that there are more than one x-parameter here - **if** there was only one, then the $y$ value *would* depend on it. But since there are more, they can instead depend on *each other* and don't really necessarily affect the $y$. All the x-parameters will cancel out and just leave the time $t$ behind.

(**A random example**: $y=5t$ and $y=\frac{10tx}{2x}$ are the same. The $y$ *doesn't* depend on the $x$ in either case, because the $x$'es "take care" of themselves.)

The whole chunk of x-direction parameters are just making it up for the $t$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I didn't even consider it as a simultaneous equation of sorts.